# PyQt pyqtgraph window resize causes colormap to reset to grayscale

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph, colormap, pyqt6

I'm facing an issue where the colormap of a pyqtgraph `ImageItem` seems to be reset to grayscale when the widget is being resized. Consider the following code

```
# PyQt6==6.4.2
# pyqtgraph==0.13.3

import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui


# Interpret image data as row-major instead of col-major
pg.setConfigOptions(imageAxisOrder='row-major')

pg.mkQApp()
win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()

# A plot area (ViewBox + axes) for displaying the image
p1 = win.addPlot(title="")

# Item for displaying image data
img = pg.ImageItem()
p1.addItem(img)

# Contrast/color control
hist = pg.HistogramLUTItem()
hist.setImageItem(img) # removing this line prevents the colorMap from changing when resizing the window
win.addItem(hist)

# Generate image data
data = np.random.normal(size=(200, 100))
img.setImage(data)
img.setColorMap(pg.colormap.get('CET-R4'))
hist.setLevels(data.min(), data.max())

win.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()
```

When running this, the window appears as expected with the 'CET-R4' colormap:
[image]

However, as soon as I resize the window, the image turns into grayscale:

[image]

I think it has to do with the `HistogramLUTItem`, since the same behaviour appears when sliding the gradient editor in the `HistogramLUTItem`.
If the `hist.setImageItem(img)` line is removed when running the code and the `HistogramLUTItem` was never linked to the `ImageItem()`, the colormap remains unchanged.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?
Any ideas on how to fix or work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HistogramLUTItem` is designed to control the LUT of the target image. So it's not a good idea to set the LUT of the image manually.

But if you insist, you can do like this using the `sigLookupTableChanged` signal. But it may be broken in the future.

```
...
hist = pg.HistogramLUTItem()
#hist.setImageItem(img)
hist.sigLookupTableChanged.connect(
    lambda: img.setColorMap(pg.colormap.get('CET-R4')))
...
```